# Updating single category data in Highcharts column chart

Tags: highcharts, column-chart

I am trying to use a column chart with single category but 4 values. The initial rendering of the graph works fine. However, when I use series[0].setData() method to update the data, it creates 4 categories as opposed to updating the single category.

Here is the [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkandhvar/td9oet5s)

```
$(function() {
  var chart;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
      chart: {
        type: 'column'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Packet Summary Stats'
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: ABC'
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: [
          'Packet Summary'
        ],
        crosshair: true
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
          text: 'Packet Count'
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' + '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y}</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
      },
      plotOptions: {
        column: {
          pointPadding: 0.2,
          borderWidth: 1
        }
      },
      series: [{
        "data": [100],
        "name": "Rx"
      }, {
        "data": [90],
        "name": "Tx"
      }, {
        "data": [10],
        "name": "Dropped"
      }, {
        "data": [10],
        "name": "No Match"
      }]
    });
  });

  $('#button').click(function() {
    chart.series[0].setData([
      [200],
      [180],
      [20],
      [20]
    ]);
  });
});
```

I am unable to figure out what am I doing wrong here. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: As an actual explanation to the answer below by *Deep3015*: you have four different series, each with one data point. But when you call your update function, you are only updating one series (`chart.series[0]`), with four data points. The chart adds three new categories to fit the three extra data points for Series 1, and has no data to add for Series 2-4.  You need to call `setData()` for each series individually (*or, don't use four different series - you can simplify both your code and your visual display by using a single series instead...*)

Comment: Quick example using single series: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/mhuzmnev/

Comment: For correct  answers only working code is not enough. proper explanation is also written. thanks for explanation

Comment: Thanks jlbriggs for the explanation. I really overlooked the series aspect and hence couldn't figure it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update chart as

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/td9oet5s/2/)

```
   $('#button').click(function() {
    chart.series[0].setData(
      [200]
    );
     chart.series[1].setData(
      [180]
    );
     chart.series[2].setData(
      [20]
    );
     chart.series[3].setData(
      [20]
    );
  });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. It works as desired now. How did I miss this!

Comment: If this answer is accepted the see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) how to accept